# Update compose page after mail update from server side in addins

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am creating an Outlook compose mode addin which hits the backend server and updates the body and attachment using MS Graph. I don't see the updates in client side unless the page is refreshed for web clients and dont seem to find any Office js APIs to cater it as well.Is there any developments on this behaviour as few posts suggests this does not already exist?

Comment: Could you describe your issue in more detail, with steps for us to reproduce? What do you mean when you say you don't see the updates in client side?

Comment: Have you checked out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0 if you only need the updated message details? Could you also let us know the platform you're testing on (Outlook Online (OWA) / Windows / Mac)?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're updating the body and attachments at the backend rather than use add-in APIs? Have you checked out [body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview#body) and [attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview#addfileattachmentasync-uri--attachmentname--options--callback-) APIs?